# Antlr Treewalker can not find token?

Tags: antlr, antlr3

I have a parser and an AST. Now i want a Treewalkergrammar. In the AST there is a token "=".

The Treewalker should find the "=" token in:

```
relationalExpression
: (numericExpression) (     (^(EQUAL relationalExpression))   
                        | (^(NOT_EQUAL relationalExpression)) 
                  )? 
;
```

Although the top token should be "=" or "!=", the compiler just looks into "numericExpression" and finds out it is not a "=" token. Finally it results the error "no viable alternative at input '='".

So "=" is the top token for the parser, but not for the treewalker.

What is wrong here?

Thank a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably meant to write `relationalExpression` in its tree form, where `numericExpression` is likely a child of `EQUAL` instead of a sibling of it.

```
// tree parser rule:
relationalExpression
  : ^(EQUAL numericExpression relationalExpression)
  | ^(NOT_EQUAL numericExpression relationalExpression)
  | numericExpression
  ;
```

This is of course assuming that your parser has a `relationalExpression` rule with either the following form (which uses the AST operator `^`):

```
// parser rule:
relationalExpression
  : numericExpression
    ( EQUAL^ relationalExpression
    | NOT_EQUAL^ relationalExpression
    )?
  ;
```

Or the following, which uses the rewrite operator `->`:

```
// parser rule:
relationalExpression
  : numericExpression
    ( EQUAL relationalExpression
      -> ^(EQUAL numericExpression relationalExpression)
    | NOT_EQUAL relationalExpression
      -> ^(NOT_EQUAL numericExpression relationalExpression)
    )?
  ;
```